Ridiculous high gas fee in production (ERC20)
I was trying to create a new smart contract with Remix. It should be something like a lottery. I made a simple function to enter the lottery:
> function enter() public payable {
>   require(msg.value == ticketPrice,"Incorrect ETH amount sent"); 
>   players.push(msg.sender);
> }

Remix was showing gas fee of around 50000. Now after deploying the contract and using the function on etherscan, I get the message of MetaMask, that the gas fee cant be calculated and MM sets the gas fee to $300. I know that with increasing the array size, the gas fee will get higher, but $300 for the first entry? Any idea how to fix this?
The complete code can be seen here

It's working as expected in my case.
Make sure you pass the correct value of 0.005 ether with the function call.


Ah heh, didn't read the code that well - of course would need to enter the right amount. Otherwise the "require" reverts the code, which causes the problems.

Yea was exactly the problem. Thanks for that. Now I know why all functions with require ask that much gas fee, because the require statement was false.
